# Cannot find IE favorites in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Favorites

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, bookmarks

Acording to [this page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/where-are-internet-favorites-hidden-in-my-p-c/c3763e34-5f67-4b26-8cf3-7726e4d3c63d), my IE favorites are supposed to be stored in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Favorites`.  However, they are not there.  When I tried to import them into Firefox, nothing got imported either.  It looks as though they are stored in some secret location.  This is a work laptop in a restrictive organization and I am not an admin.

How can I access my IE favorites for backup and transfer to another browser?

Comment: You will need to ask your IT Staff where they are located. You can also right click on any Bookmark you have and check the `General` of the resulting `Property Dialog` that is where the actual bookmark is located.  I am going to guess your checking the wrong profile, I am also not aware, of anyway to change this location.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on a favorite in IE, select Properties. In the General tab the location is given.

Comment: I want to export ALL favorites in bulk, not one by one

Comment: Sure, my idea was that you can determine the folder where ALL favorites are stored with that procedure! Otherwise we can only guess...

Comment: It shows that favorite `FavA` is in directory `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\FavFolder1` but when I went into `C:\Users\%USERNAME%`, there was no `FavFolder1` subdir

Comment: You can try to turn on the display of hidden files (Control Panel -> Folder Options -> View -> Show hidden files) or just copy & paste the path into explorer's adress bar.

Comment: I have that already but no directory contents are shown

Comment: Hm, can you check with `dir /a C:\Users\%USERNAME%` in a console window if there's something special with the folder (e.g. junction) and is `attrib C:\Users\%USERNAME%\FavFolder1` working?

Comment: did that, `desktop.ini` is the only hidden item

Comment: So, the attrib command does not produce an error?! Can you `cd` into FavFolder1?

Comment: Nope.  Tried that too.

Comment: Sorry, no more ideas :-( Perhaps you should rise a new question and give some more details of your setup.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to see under

```
%USERPROFILE%\Favorites
```

Comment: yes, it is the same as `C:\Users\%USERNAME%`